# xml nodeValue string interpreted as number

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm parsing through an XML document using jquery, and seem to be having some problems with the `nodeValue` of an attribute. I've got the following element:

```
<chapter number="1" formattednumber="1." />
```

...where the attribute `formattednumber` is the string that will eventually be displayed in the UI. That's fine and well, until we look at:

```
element.attributes.item("formattednumber").nodeValue
```

Which returns a `number` instead of a string value (i.e., a `1` instead of a `"1."` -- interpreting the dot as a decimal point and removing it). Is there any way I can get the text value out of the attribute instead?

Comment: Did you try `element.getAttribute('formattednumber')`

Comment: Yes! That's it -- do you want to write it up so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: Sure, doing it right now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the attribute from an XML node as a string, you can use `getAttribute()`

```
element.getAttribute('formattednumber')
```